# Print all numbers from 1000 to 9999 array, while loop unexpected behaviour

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    int PIN[4] = {1, 0, 0, 0}; // Start from 1000
    while ((PIN[0] != 9) && (PIN[1] != 9) && (PIN[2] != 9) && (PIN[3] != 9)) { // Stop at 9999

        PIN[3]++;
        if (PIN[3] > 9) {
            PIN[3] = 0;
            PIN[2]++;
            if (PIN[2] > 9) {
                PIN[2] = 0;
                PIN[1]++;
                if (PIN[1] > 9) {
                    PIN[1] = 0;
                    PIN[0]++;
                }
            }

        }
        //  Print all numbers from 1000 to 9999
        printf("%d %d %d %d \n", PIN[0], PIN[1], PIN[2], PIN[3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 2 
1 0 0 3 
1 0 0 4 
1 0 0 5 
1 0 0 6 
1 0 0 7 
1 0 0 8 
1 0 0 9 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I use the OR operator instead of the AND operator inside the while it stops at 9999 which is the desired behaviour.
Why this happens?

I want to do
while(every digit is different from 9)

like this:

```
...
9 9 9 3 
9 9 9 4 
9 9 9 5 
9 9 9 6 
9 9 9 7 
9 9 9 8 
9 9 9 9 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: In “1 0 0 9”, is every digit different from 9?

Comment: I think I start to get it but why the OR operator stops when the array is {9, 9, 9, 9} ?

Comment: That's a really inefficient way of iteration.

Comment: What is a more efficient way of iterating?

Comment: ```for(size_t i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) { /** YOUR CODE **/ }```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `(PIN[0] != 9) || (PIN[1] != 9) || (PIN[2] != 9) || (PIN[3] != 9)` when the `PIN` values are 1, 0, 0, and 9. Then:

- `1 != 9` is true.
- `0 != 9` is true.
- `0 != 9` is true.
- `9 != 9` is false.
- `true || true || true || false` is true.

In more detail:  `||` is true if either operand is true, and `true || true || true || false` is structured as `((true || true) || true) || false`. In that, `true || true` evaluates as true, so we have `(true || true) || true`, which becomes `true || true`, which becomes `true`.

Consider the expression when the values are 9, 9, 9, 9. Then:

- `9 != 9` is false.
- `9 != 9` is false.
- `9 != 9` is false.
- `9 != 9` is false.
- `false || false || false || false` is false.

In more detail:  `||` is false if both of its operands are false. `false || false || false || false` is structured as `((false || false) || false) || false`. In that, `false || false` evaluates as false, so we have `(false || false) || false)`, which becomes `false || false`, which becomes `false`.

Comment: I think I understand it now:

when I use AND and one of the digits is 9 then for example for:

1 0 0 9

not every digit is different from 9 so the condition is false

but when I use OR:

1 0 0 9

only one of the digits makes it false but the others are true

so the condition only stops at 9 9 9 9

when all of them are false

Answer (score 0):

`while ((PIN[0] != 9) && (PIN[1] != 9) && (PIN[2] != 9) && (PIN[3] != 9)) {` is saying "while [0] is not nine and [1] is not 9 and [2] is not nine and [3] is not nine". So as soon as any one digit IS nine the loop ends.

You want to end when they are all 9. So you want to end when `PIN[0] == 9 && PIN[1] == 9 && PIN[2] == 9 &&PIN[3] == 9` so you want to keep going while that is false. `while(!(PIN[0] == 9 && PIN[1] == 9 && PIN[2] == 9 && PIN[3] == 9))`

Answer (score -1):

You are effectively trying to achieve the following:

```c
for (int pin0=1; pin0<10; ++pin0) {
for (int pin1=0; pin1<10; ++pin1) {
for (int pin2=0; pin2<10; ++pin2) {
for (int pin3=0; pin3<10; ++pin3) {
   ...
}}}}
```

The difference is that your approach allows you to have a variable number of digits. If that's not something you need, then this approach would be simpler.

---

As for the problem with your code, it's that you have the wrong operation. You loop while no digit is nine, but you want to loop while any digit isn't nine.

```c
PIN[0] != 9 || PIN[1] != 9 || PIN[2] != 9 || PIN[3] != 9
```

You could also think of it as looping until all the digits are nine.

```c
!( PIN[0] == 9 && PIN[1] == 9 && PIN[2] == 9 && PIN[3] == 9 )
```

---

Alternative solution:

```c
for (int pin=1000; pin<10000; ++pin) {
   int pin0 = ( pin / 1000 ) % 10;
   int pin1 = ( pin /  100 ) % 10;
   int pin2 = ( pin /   10 ) % 10;
   int pin3 = ( pin /    1 ) % 10;
   ...
}
```

This approach can also be used with a variable number of digits.

Comment: I don't understand why OR works:

It reads to me while(any number is different than 9)

so it should stop when one of them is 9

Comment: No, only when *all* of them are 9. If any number is not `9`, then the whole number cannot be `9 9 9 9`.

Comment: Re "*It reads to me while(any number is different than 9).*" This is correct, and this is what you want. If only one of them is 9, then there are numbers different than 9. So "any number is different than 9" is true, and the loop continues. It doesn't stop, contrary to your claim that it should. The only time "any number is different than 9" is false is when all the numbers are 9. (`!any(condition)` == `all(!condition)`)